# Numerical instability in the inverse Laplace transform

Tags: python, numerics, stability, inverse, laplacian

I have a problem with Laplace inversion and my function is not numerically stable for the Laplace inverse, but I do not understand the cause of this problem.
Here is my code and graph of this problem. Does anyone have any idea? I have also tried all 3 `Dehoog` `Stehfest` and `Talbot`, they all have a different type of instabillity

```
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def Laplace_Max(s):
    #mp.dps = 100
    A= s**(5/4)/ (
        0.00480931 + 
        0.0244077*s**(1/4) + 
        0.0129056*mp.exp(-35*s)*s**(1/4) + 
        0.00329167*mp.exp(0.707997*s)*s**(1/4) * mp.gammainc(0.0, 35.708*s,mp.inf, regularized=True) - 
        0.00530593*mp.gammainc(1.25, 35*s,mp.inf,   regularized=True)
    )
    return A
t_R_inv = np.linspace(1,1200,12000)
Max_R=np.zeros(len(t_R_inv))
for i in range(len(t_R_inv)):
    Max_R[i]=mp.invertlaplace(Laplace_Max, t_R_inv[i], method = 'stehfest', dps = 100, degree = 1000)
plt.plot(Max_R)
```

Update
The inverse laplace of this function!

$\frac{1}{s}^{\frac{5}{4}}\cdot (0.00480931 + 0.02440766 \cdot s^{\frac{1}{4}} + 
   0.0129056 \cdot e^{-35 \cdot s} \cdot s^{\frac{1}{4}}+ 
   0.003291670 \cdot e^{0.7079967\cdot s} \cdot s^{\frac{1}{4}}
    \cdot \Gamma[0, 35.7079967 \cdot s] - 
   0.00530593 \cdot\Gamma[1.25, 35\cdot s])$

[image]

Comment: Please write mathematically what the problem is that you are trying to solve and what these solution methods you mention are that way people have an easier time helping you.

Comment: From the graph it is hard to see where *exactly* the region of instability is. It *seems to be* around $t=30$? Please provide a numerical range for this.

Comment: @njuffa jup around 35

Comment: @EMP so I did it

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform is ill-conditioned: https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1016/j.amc.2013.03.112; maybe you can fight it a bit by (say) high precision.

Comment: If the *problem* is ill-conditioned, you can't really expect that different methods are gonna help.